# How can I get the context in the finish() method?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I'm just rtying to display an offerwall when someone is leaving the application, so I have placed the `finish()` method:

```
@Override
public void finish() {
    super.finish();
    MobileCore.init(this.getContext(), "xxx", MobileCore.LOG_TYPE.DEBUG, MobileCore.AD_UNITS.OFFERWALL);

    MobileCore.setStickeezReadyListener(new OnReadyListener() {
        @Override
        public void onReady(MobileCore.AD_UNITS adUnit) {
            if (adUnit == MobileCore.AD_UNITS.OFERWALL) {
                MobileCore.showOferWall(getActivity());
            }
        }
    });
}
```

But I have problems. First of all with this code `this.getContext()` and also with this `getActivity()`

I know that I can not access the activity this way, but I'm extremely confused at the moment. I know that I'm missing a very small part here. Can you give me a push?

Comment: This is a really bad design approach for an Android app. If I installed an app which forced an advert to be shown every time I hit the BACK button, I'd install it straight away.

Comment: @Squonk The ad is shown only once - when you leave the application(MainActivity).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Activity class extends Context` so actually `Activity` is instance of `Context`, in `onFinish` the system is trying to destroy the `Activity` so there must be no jobs still working related to this `Activity`, if you still need a `Context` you can use `this.getApplicationContext`.

Answer (score 1):

To call the outer class in a nested class (in your case an anonymous class) use the class name of the outer one:

```
YourOuterClass.this
```

Answer (score 1):

Your activity's context will remain valid until you call `super.finish()`. So don't call it until you're done.

If you can't do that, use the application context.